# Using ":=" in SQLQuery

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate

I have a query that is calling a postgres stored procedure with named parameters. The procedure can take many parameters, most of which have defaults, and I only want to use a couple.  The SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT {(mytable).*} FROM myStoredProc(:p1, _namedParam := TRUE);
```

I bind in `p1` and add `mytable` as an entity. However, I get `NHibernate.QueryException : Not all named parameters have been set: ['']` -- it appears it's from the `:=` in the named parameter.

Is there a way to escape that colon so that I can get past this? I bind all my strings and such already, but I don't think I can bind syntax like this, so I need NHibernate to stop complaining about this non-parameter.  This stored proc takes something like a dozen or so parameters, and the one I'm setting here is the last one, so I'd rather not insert all the defaults explicitly in my C# code.

Comment: You could to use alternative notation, `=>` instead of `:=`.

Comment: @Abelisto you should post that as an answer rather than a comment. While it does appear that NHibernate can't handle colons anywhere other than named parameters in their CreateSQLQuery method (I've been pouring over their code over the last while), this should bypass it for my purposes. It's still a parsing bug they should fix, but this can work around it pretty quickly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `:=` (which is mentioned as an "older syntax" in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CALLING-FUNCS-NAMED)) you could to use `=>`:

```
SELECT {(mytable).*} FROM myStoredProc(:p1, _namedParam => TRUE);
```

For now I don't remember any other places where colon used in the PostgreSQL syntax except the type casting like `<value>::<type>` (`'1'::integer` for instance) but it could be simply replaced by more general syntax like `cast(<value> as <type>)` or shortly `<type> <value>`.